# What is correct/Pythonic way to change a setting in an imported package?

Tags: python, django, python-import

What is correct/Pythonic way to change a setting in an imported package?

For example, I want to change the DEFAULT_PROTOCOL value to 0 (zero) in the constants.py file in django-picklefield for use in conjunction with django-constance.

But more than just this example, I have several cases in Mezzanine and Cartridge among other imported packages where I want to change a value in their settings.py or another file.

Do I need to fork the package repository, make my changes and import the local modified package in my project?

Thanks.

Comment: you can install the repo in editable mode using the “-e” flag that way any changes to the package get reflected in imports without having to reinstall

Comment: You can pass a protocol when you define a `PickledObjectField`, why do you need to override the default?

Comment: @IainShelvington Thank you for your tip but the Constance package makes the call to the picklefield package for the PickledObjectField, so I would need to edit constance/backends/database/models.py in the imported Constance package to pass the protocol.  So my question still stands: what is the normal/accepted/pythonic way to customize code in an imported package?